# A Roman Emergency

Tags: riddle, mathematics, cipher

Recently a tablet from ancient rome was discovered containing a list of cryptic numbers. Most of the numbers are easy to read, but there are scratches over the last three making them difficult to decipher:

```
2
4
2

2
1
1
5
1

11
1
2
5
2

2000
10
2000
2
220

200
1
2
4
20

1100
1
110
2
????
????
????
```

What are the last three numbers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**ANSWER**

> 9
> 1
> 1

Explanation...

> Thanks to @charfellow because it is indeed an alphametic!  ...But the title gives it away. :( I personally had to replace the numerals with unrelated roman characters so that it wouldn't interfere.
>
> A quick lookup of 2-digit squares revealed only one that fit the pattern $MM^2 = CCXX$, which is $$88^2 = 7744$$  Following the logic from there, we only have one digit left to solve. The key is the $$XI-II \gt II$$ equation. Since we already found $X$ from the previous equation, we know that $I$ must be less than 4, or else we'd be getting into negatives. The only digit that fulfills the inequality is 1. So, in all, we have...
>
>  `I = 1`
>  `X = 4`
>  `C = 7`
>  `M = 8`
>
>  Using these values, we can fill in the equation set.
>
> $$\begin{cases}11\ge11\\11-1\gt1\\41-11\gt11\\88*88=7744\\77-11\ge44\\87-74=????\end{cases}$$
>
>   The missing value is 13. Using only the digits we found with the alphametic, we must find an equation that equals 13 and make sure that the translation back into Roman numerals yields a legal value.  Luckily, we find one right away with $87-74=14-1$.  In Roman numeral alphametic, the new equation becomes `IX-I`. In plain Roman numerals, it becomes `IX I I`, or, `911`.

Comment: Can you show the steps that result in that answer? I'm getting a different answer with my steps (although your explanation is pretty solid). To be clear: it's the end of a long day for me.

Comment: Working on it. Just wanted to get an answer up.

Comment: It's up. I was new to MathJax. :\

Comment: Nice job, I was worried I had made it too hard but not for you!

Comment: This answer only makes sense if somebody in ancient Rome knew positional number systems before they were invented.

Comment: Ah, I see now. My answers aren't wrong per se, it's just that your answer actually fits the title ;P

Answer (score 7):

### Not an answer

I doubt that an ancient Roman tablet would have numbers in Hindu-Arabic, so I've translated the numbers to Roman Numerals, in case it helps someone else solve the puzzle.

> `II`
>  `IV`
>  `II`
>
>  `II`
>  `I`
>  `I`
>  `V`
>  `I`
>
>  `XI`
>  `I`
>  `II`
>  `V`
>  `II`
>
>  `MM`
>  `X`
>  `MM`
>  `II`
>  `CCXX`
>
>  `CC`
>  `I`
>  `II`
>  `IV`
>  `XX`
>
>  `MC`
>  `I`
>  `CX`
>  `II`
>  `????`
>  `????`
>  `????`

Comment: Came here to do that. You beat me to it. :P

Comment: You had time - I triple checked myself :P

Comment: I was responding to other notifications and just had the translation sitting around saved in my URL bar. Plus, I'd put everything in horizontally without spaces until a line break. Eh, I just went ahead and monospaced everything for the sake of alignment in case it matters.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could monospace.  Thanks!

Comment: Technically, they're in code blocks `\`xyz\`` which are usually gray but the nature of the spoiler box keeps 'em yellow. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Khale_Kitha's partial answer...

> Alphametics?
>  Let's turn things on their sides...
>  $$II \ge II$$ 
>  $$II - I > I$$ 
>  $$XI - II > II$$
>  $$MM  x  MM = CCXX$$ 
>  $$CC - II \ge XX$$
>  $$MC - CX = ????$$
>  $$????$$
>  $$????$$
>  So the last line seems like it *could* be 1100, 1, and 110 (MC - CX = MC - CX?)

Solving time!

> The only valid value for $M$ is $8$; $C$ is $7$ and $X$ is $4$
>  Because $$77 - 44 \ge II,$$
>  I = $1$ or $2$ or $3$
>  Because $XI - II > II$, $X > 2*I$, so $I = 1$
>  Last line: $MC - CX = 87 - 74 = 13$
>  The second number must be a plus or minus, but we have no minus, so #2 is $I$ (1)
>  The last line must be 87 - 74 or 84 - 71
>  The 3 numbers are $MC, I, CX$ (1100 1 110) or $MX, I, CI$ (1010 1 11)

All of that said, I like feelin's answer, and I hope I made a mistake! :P

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that.  Nice.

Comment: Looks like I X C and M have alternate values. Might be worth trying replacing with numbers. X > I, C > I + X, M >= 3

Comment: Also M > C. I'm heading to dinner but if it's not solved when I get back I'll give it a go.

Comment: I have to say, this was an absolute revelation! Total genius on finding the proper format. Nice work!

Comment: @feelinferrety I don't get credit for the substitution?

Comment: @Z.Dailey -- Sorry, not sure what you're referring to. I solved charfellow's alphametic when that was the only part of the answer showing, but spent forever formatting my answer, so didn't comment until much later (only Khale_Kitha's comment had been posted at the time of my last viewing).

Answer (score 1):

## Not an Answer: Alternate Formatting

> Single line breaks -> spaces, double line breaks -> new row:
>
> `II IV II`
> `II I I V I`
> `XI I II V II`
> `MM X MM II CCXX`
> `CC I II IV XX`
> `MC I CX II ???? ???? ????`

OR

> Only double line breaks are preserved:
>
> `IIIVII`
> `IIIIVI`
> `XIIIIVII`
> `MMXMMIICCXX`
> `CCIIIIVXX`
> `MCICXII????????????`

OR

> Order of placement in each individual list is maintained but lists are otherwise combined (AKA rows are kept but column is reduced to 1):
>
> `IIIIXIMMCCMC`
> `IVIIIXII`
> `IIIIMMIICX`
> `VVIIIVII`
> `IIICCXXXX????`
> `????`
> `????`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @charfellow's answer...

> It could be... 
>  9
>  9
>  0
>  
>  "990" is what you get when you subtract 110 from 1100.

Comment: That doesn't exactly follow the format proposed.